# php - get values from array alphabetically as list group

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to get values from MySQL array as alphabetically, and I want results like:

```
[B] => Array  (
        [id] => 6
        [firstname] => Bon
        [lastname] => Jone
    ),
    Array  (
        [id] => 7
        [firstname] => bon
        [lastname] => doe
    )
[H] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [firstname] => Hassan
        [lastname] => Ilyas
    )

[J] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [firstname] => John
        [lastname] => Doe
    )
```

Here is the code of what I have tried.

**edited**

```
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conx'],"SELECT * FROM $users_table ORDER BY firstname ASC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $row['alphabets'] = ucfirst($firstname[0]);
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

But it outputs like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [firstname] => Bon
        [lastname] => Jone
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [firstname] => bon
        [lastname] => doe
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [firstname] => Hassan
        [lastname] => Ilyas
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [firstname] => John
        [lastname] => Doe
    )
```

How can I get output like this:

### A

Adam Smith

Alan smith

### B

Bone Doe

Bone Joe

### J

John Smith

.... etc

Comment: Why you don't sort it in mysql query?

Comment: already sorted that before, sorry I didn't show that in my post
`$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conx'],"SELECT * FROM $users_table ORDER BY firstname ASC");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ucfirst** returns the entire string with the first letter capitalised, you'll need to grab just the first letter with **substr** first.

```
$data = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $key = strtoupper($firstname[0]))
    $data[$key][] = $row;
}
```

To get the output (roughly) like you want, try something like:

```
foreach ($data as $letter => $rows)
{
    echo "<h1>{$letter}</h1>", PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "<p>{$row['firstname']} {$row['lastname']}</p>", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: but you didn't see that I am only getting first letter of that string by useing index 0
`$firstname[0]`

Comment: and where from this `$i` is comes from?

Comment: Was rushing through that a bit, sorry. Edited.

Comment: ok, this is nice suggestion, and looks fine in array output.
but how I can print this into string like I showed in my example above in question

Comment: I've added some sample output, you might need to tweak the HTML a bit to get it looking exactly right.

Comment: It's just a new-line, makes the output look a bit more readable.

Comment: great and awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt will not do what you want. To achieve this, you will have to create a nested array, then on each iteration check the first letter of the *firstname*. Check if that letter already exists as a key in the array, and create an item in your array with an empty array as its value, it if it doesn't, and then add the row data to it to that newly created empty array.

```
$data = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $firstLetter = strtoupper($row["firstname"][0]); // convert to upper case so all are the same
    if (array_key_exists($firstLetter, $data) === false) $data[$firstLetter] = [];
    // now just add the row data:
    $data[$firstLetter][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: give the example to echo it out

Comment: `if (array_key_exists($firstLetter, $data) === false) $data[$firstLetter] = [];` is not necessary because pushing child elements with square brace syntax can be done without explicitly declaring the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

**First use Order in your MySQL Query**: ... ORDER BY firstname ASC

**Create Arrays for Alphabets using PHP**:

```
$Alphabetic_Array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Alphabetic_Array[$row['firstname'][0]][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: already used `$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conx'],"SELECT * FROM $users_table ORDER BY firstname ASC");`

Comment: give an example to apply in foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest you to sort records in your query, otherwise you have to sort resulting array before grouping it:

```
    SELECT * from tablename
  ORDER BY firstname ASC, lastname ASC
```

Then, you can use `array_map` to group your array:

```
$result = array();
array_map
(
    function( $row ) use( &$result )
    {
        $result[strtoupper(substr($row['firstname'],0,1))][] = $row;
    },
    $data
);
```

(Note that we have to call `$result` by reference)

Now the `$result` is an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [firstname] => bon
                    [lastname] => doe
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [firstname] => Bon
                    [lastname] => Jone
                )
        )
    [H] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [firstname] => Hassan
                    [lastname] => Ilyas
                )
        )
    [J] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [firstname] => John
                    [lastname] => Doe
                )
        )
)
```

---

If you want/can use `PDO` instead of `mysqli_`, you can obtain desired result directly from MySQL query. Set your query in this way:

```
    SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(firstname,1,1)) as initial, tablename.* from tablename
  ORDER BY firstname ASC, lastname ASC
```

and then, fetching in in this way:

```
$data->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP );
```

your `$data` will contain desired array, without need of additional processing.
The `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` option groups fetched results by first column returned by query, in your case the capitalized firstname first letter.

Comment: check my updated question, I already used that result 
`$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conx'],"SELECT * FROM $users_table ORDER BY firstname ASC");`

Comment: OK, then in the answer there is also the code to groups array. (And to do all with one-line of code, but ... using PDO)

Comment: tell me the way by my procedure,
and where to use your code? in loop or outside that?

Comment: above procedure is to use outside the loop, but you can also use in your original loop by this way: `$data[strtoupper(substr($row['firstname'],0,1))][] = $row;` . Or, using your own method: `$data[ucfirst($firstname[0])][] = $row;` The error in your approach is `$data[]`: you have to use `$data[LETTER][]` instead. I hope I was clear. :)

Comment: how to test it in foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

What about letting MYSQL do the logic?

```html
SELECT * FROM users_table, SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, 1) as initial ORDER BY firstname ASC
```

Then you just can append each line to an array

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $Alphabetic_Array[$row['initial'] = $row;
}
```

It's just pseudo code but I think the idea is pretty clear